# button that effects 2 different states

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a blue grey button that when pressed, turns green and then when pressed again turns back to blue grey. I now need that same button to also tick up an integer when pressed and then to tick down the integer when pressed again.
here is the code:

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int secondaryLeftCounter = 0;                                 //integer to change

  bool so1HasBeenPressed01 = false;


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            so1HasBeenPressed01 = !so1HasBeenPressed01;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 30.0,
          height: 30.0,
          color: so1HasBeenPressed01
              ? Colors.green
              : Colors.blueGrey[900],
        ),
      ),
    ),],);
```

I can make it work if there are two buttons (one for ticking up and one for ticking down) but am struggling to get it to work with everything happening with the same button.
cheers

Comment: What do you mean from tick up and tick down? are you want increase int to 1 and then decrease it to 0? so what's the different with boolean?

Comment: use the same variable "so1HasBeenPressed01" as the condition to tick up and tick down

Comment: yes, to increase by 1 when pressed and then decrease by 1 when pressed again.

Comment: yes but the problem is i don't know how to do that in code form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        so1HasBeenPressed01 = !so1HasBeenPressed01;
        if(so1HasBeenPressed01)
          secondaryLeftCounter++;
        else
          secondaryLeftCounter--;
      });
    },
```